# "Informing" — Gerund instead of Verb+Object?

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

I think if we take *informing* as a noun in this sentence, it should be fine. What are your views on the grammaticality of the following sentence?

> He left me without informing.

Comment: Please be aware that StackExchange disapproves of cross-posting on multiple SE sites. I think this question will be better received on ELL, where you first posted it.

Comment: I think there is a subtle question here about gerunds, not just a simple confusion of transitive and intransitive usage. So the ELL answer would not suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Inform is a transitive verb; as such, it requires an object. He left without informing whom? You, or someone else? If, in fact, it was you whom he failed to inform:

- He left [me] without {informing/alerting/telling} **me**.

Note that you can remove the *first* "me", not the *second* one.

Now, if you write it the way you wanted to write it,

- He left me without informing.

and you expect the reader to take this as a noun (the gerund, "informing"), you are asking the reader to parse it like this:

- He left me without (something).

So you are saying it's like :

- He left me without bread.
- He left me without a clue.

This means that YOU are the one lacking the item.

Now, if the item is "informing", that means the act of informing; that is, *the act* of telling someone something. So, leaving you without "informing" would mean that he left *without giving YOU a chance to inform HIM!*

- He left without letting me inform him.

Of course, this is not what you meant. Because the *thing* he left you without was **information** (*the result* of being informed).

- He left me without information.

But this phrasing does not clarify that it was from HIM that you expected that information. It could be just any information.

The other problem is that "informing" and "information" are not **countable nouns**. So we don't say *one informing, two informings*, and we don't say *an informing* or *an information*.

However If you were to use a **countable noun** (for instance, "warning"), it would sound OK to use the **indefinite article** "a"

- He left me without a warning.

This, I believe, conveys your intended meaning.

But since "warn" is also a transitive verb, you could also say.

- He left [me] without warning **me**.

I hope this helps you to understand the subtle difference.

Comment: I agree on this critical part: 
   " _He left [me] without {informing/alerting/telling} me._

Note that you can remove the first "me", not the second one. "

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock Yes, I can clearly understand it now.